# How to create a volume from a local path in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

With command line arguments, I can indicate that I want to mount a local directory as a volume:

```
docker run -i -t -v /path/to/directory/:/mount/point testimage
```

However, I can't find anything to describe the syntax to `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile to do the same thing. Can anyone explain what this looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dockerfiles only define the right side (which paths within the container are volumes) -- not the local/left side.

The mapping is done during container creation, not image creation.

Comment: @user2105103I guess I don't understand what good specifying this in the Dockerfile does then? What does the `docker run` command turn into to take advantage of "predefining" which paths in the container are volumes?

Comment: It creates the directory, flags it as a mount, and excludes it from the union file system.   Not required, but nicely sets up the container.

Comment: So just to confirm, if I add `VOLUME /mount/point` to the Dockerfile, I still use literally the same command to start the container had I not done that - i.e. `docker run -i -t -v /path/to/directory/:/mount/point testimage`?

Comment: Yup.   Images (what results when you docker pull/docker build) have zero knowledge of your *host filesystem by design.    All that wiring up happens when you launch a container (from an image).